# frozennode administrator relationship restrict by tenant

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have three Laravel models within a multitenanted app:

```
Tenant {}

Company {
    public function tenant() {
        return $this->belongsTo('Tenant');
    }
    public function group() {
        return $this->belongsTo('Group');
    }
}

Group {
    public function companies() {
        return $this->hasMany('Company');
    }
        public function tenant() {
            return $this->belongsTo('Tenant');
        }
}
```

I am building an admin interface for my app using Frozennode Administrator, so the super admin can change stuff and so on. I want to be able to change the group of a company:

```
'edit_fields' => [
    ],
    'group' => [
        'title' => 'Group',
        'type' => 'relationship',
        'name_field' => "title",
        //'constraints' => ['tenant' => 'tenant']
    ]
]
```

But my constraint does not work. How can I limit the groups shown to those matching the tenant that the company belongs to?

Answer (score 0):

This is relatively simple. Just define a new relationship in your Company model like so: (and use this instead of "group" in your administrator config file):

```
public function tenant_group() {
    return $this->belongsTo('Group')->whereTenantId(Session::get('current_tenant_id'));
}
```

The above code assumes you have a session variable called "current_tenant_id" which determines the current users' tenant. You can replace that with something else, perhaps something like this:

```
Auth::getUser()['tenant_id']
```